# Firebase Firestore REST POST Request - Query and Filter using structured query

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-apis-explorer

**URL**:

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/projectname/databases/(default)/documents/:runQuery
```

**POST buffer**:

```
{ "structuredQuery": {"from": [{"collectionId": "example","allDescendants": true}],"where": {"fieldFilter": {"field": {"fieldPath": "Invoiceno"},"op": EQUAL,"value": {"stringValue": "1"}}}}}
```

**Response**:

```
[{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"{ \"structuredQuery\": {\"from\": [{\"collectionId\": \"example\",\"allDescendants\": true}],\"where\": {\"fieldFilter\": {\"field\": {\"fieldPath\": \"Invoiceno\"},\"op\": EQUAL,\"value\": {\"stringValue\": \"1\"}}}}}\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field '{ \"structuredQuery\": {\"from\": [{\"collectionId\": \"example\",\"allDescendants\": true}],\"where\": {\"fieldFilter\": {\"field\": {\"fieldPath\": \"Invoiceno\"},\"op\": EQUAL,\"value\": {\"stringValue\": \"1\"}}}}}' could not be found in request message.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"{ \"structuredQuery\": {\"from\": [{\"collectionId\": \"example\",\"allDescendants\": true}],\"where\": {\"fieldFilter\": {\"field\": {\"fieldPath\": \"Invoiceno\"},\"op\": EQUAL,\"value\": {\"stringValue\": \"1\"}}}}}\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field '{ \"structuredQuery\": {\"from\": [{\"collectionId\": \"example\",\"allDescendants\": true}],\"where\": {\"fieldFilter\": {\"field\": {\"fieldPath\": \"Invoiceno\"},\"op\": EQUAL,\"value\": {\"stringValue\": \"1\"}}}}}' could not be found in request message."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
]
```

I have given this for POST REST function, but i am unable to get the data.

Comment: Does this error occur at other document paths? e.g. `... /documents/collection1/doc1:runQuery`

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is in your `fieldFilter`, where you are using the op as `EQUAL` and it should be `"EQUAL"` with quotes, try changing it to the following and it should work:

```
"fieldFilter": 
{
    "field": 
    {
        "fieldPath": "Invoiceno"
    },
    "op": "EQUAL",
    "value": {"stringValue": "1"}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I discover you need to create an index on root Document.

So when you run the query all is fine.

[https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{projectId}/databases/(default)/documents:runQuery](https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/%7BprojectId%7D/databases/(default)/documents:runQuery)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

"fieldFilter":
{
"field":
{
"fieldPath": "Invoiceno"
},
"op": "EQUAL",
"value": {"stringValue": "1"}
}{ "structuredQuery": {"from": [{"collectionId": "example","allDescendants": true}],"where": {"fieldFilter": {"field": {"fieldPath": "Invoiceno"},"op": EQUAL,"value": {"stringValue": "1"}}}}}